# Creating a kml file using vba - Not saving properly

Tags: vba, kml, google-earth

I'm attempting to use VBA to take in some coordinates from a SQL table, create some code that sits in an excel tab that is then saved as a .kml file and open the file in Google Earth.

When the code creates the kml file it then opens GE but nothing happens (as in, it doesn't show the coordinates in the sidebar and doesn't point to anything).
Similarly, when I navigate to the kml file manually and open it in GE, nothing happens. 
However, if I go back to the excel tab that is being saved as .kml, copy/paste the code into notepad and manually save as .kml, the file opens in GE and displays the coordinates from the code.
I have stripped the code back to the minimum required to highlight my problem (see below).
From what I've observed it would seem I'm not saving the file properly.

```
Sub Mapping()

Range("A1").Value = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
Range("A2").Value = "<kml xmlns=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"""
Range("A3").Value = "xmlns:gx=""http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"" "
Range("A4").Value = "xmlns:kml=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"" "
Range("A5").Value = "xmlns:atom=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">"
Range("A6").Value = "<Document>"
Range("A7").Value = " <Placemark> <name>" & "Name here..." & "</name> <description>" & "Testing" & "</description>"
Range("A8").Value = "<Style> <IconStyle> <scale>1.2</scale> <Icon> <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon16.png</href> </Icon> </IconStyle> </Style> "
Range("A9").Value = "<Point> <coordinates>" & " -114.232195463845,53.0160219116952,0" & "</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark>"
Range("A10").Value = "</Document> </kml> "

ActiveSheet.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\KMLTESTING4.kml"

Dim KMLLoc As String
KMLLoc = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\KMLTESTING4.kml"
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & KMLLoc, vbNormalFocus)


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just SaveAs a kml file? Would you not write to a txt file and save that as kml? I'm not that familiar with the format.

Comment: I think you need to tell SaveAs what file format you'd like. Probably text by the sounds of it. You can look here for the file formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Added FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter to the end of my save and now working fine. Thank you both

Comment: @user2842721 you could post that as your answer, and then accept it as the answer, it will give you some rep AND it may well help others with similar issues in the future (otherwise I'll sneak in, in that split second you let your guard down and steal it. And I'd do it again!! (Simpsons ref) Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter to the end of my save and now working fine.